# Is beef a tamo bhakshanam?

Tags: food

I am a practicing Hindu from Kerala, India. I and my parents are vegetarians. Hindus from my part of the country, however, (Kerala) do eat beef, excluding certain upper castes, *pujaris* (from all castes) and some Hindus who are vegetarian by choice.
I am unaware as to whether this is because of the presence and influence of Communists/Marxists/Non-Hindus in Kerala or if this is actually a historic practice.

What do our *smritis* and *shrutis* have to say about *gomaamsam* (beef)? Is it *tamo bhakshanam*? Or is it left to personal/regional preference?

Comment: In my part of the country bengal ,  We say that there is destruction of dharma after eating beef  . There is a reasn for that . The Reason is these four are always busy behind the protection and proper functioning of society . Brahmin  , Gau  ,  Vaidya , Bhagwan  . 
Brahmans will do puja and ask for well being of others even if they dont have proper resources . similarly cows give milk even if they are not proper fed after giving milk . Cows are animals which give feed another species no other animal does that . killing itself is adharma .

Comment: Any meat is considered a tamsic / rajasic according to vaishnavites . Thats why vaishnavites brahmans dont eat it , because the purification of thought after eating it very difficult .

Comment: Eating beef has the same punishment as eating meat.